# Empty drawable folder Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I use Android studio and suddenly my drawable folder became empty ( *drawable* and *drawable-hdpi* folders). The other drawable folders still exist and are not empty.

Anyone knows why ?

Comment: Are they empty in your file system too?

Comment: Yes, they are. I found that he folder has been suddenly broken and not yet accessible